# Why does having a www CNAME in Cloudflare does not work and return Error 523

Tags: dns, cloudflare, cname

Hey so How to setup CNAME DNS for www to point towards the root domain. The Root cname works but the www CName doesn't. i have it like the this
[image: CNAME Setup for WWW domain]

I have my react page hosted on Cloudflare pages, but when I go to https://www.stron.ml It returns the following error. I am kinda new to web hosting stuff .

> ## Error 523
>
> Ray ID: 650b0c9bcc380b97 • 2021-05-17 07:14:30 UTC
>
> ### Origin is unreachable

I tried even adding a subdomain like dev. but I got the same error ,
Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at the moment your redirection seems working, it could've been simply a matter of propagation time.
Anyway, keep in mind that pointing a CNAME to another CNAME is discouraged by the [official RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1912#section-2.4), so pointing your www subdomain to stron.ml, while stron.ml is already a CNAME should be avoided:

> Don't use CNAMEs in combination with RRs which point to other names like MX, CNAME, PTR and NS.